# Encrypting in NetSuite Suitescript and decrypting in java application

Tags: java, encryption, netsuite

I need to encrypt a string using SuiteScript, send it to a web service written in Java, and decrypt it there.

Using SuiteScript I'm able to encrypt and decrypt without any issue. But when I use the same key in java, I get different errors.

```
var x = "string to be encrypted";
var key = 'EB7CB21AA6FB33D3B1FF14BBE7DB4962';
var encrypted = nlapiEncrypt(x,'aes',key);
var decrypted = nlapiDecrypt(encrypted ,'aes',key);
```

*^^works fine^^*

The code in Java

```
final String strPassPhrase = "EB7CB21AA6FB33D3B1FF14BBE7DB4962"; //min 24 chars

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede");
    SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESedeKeySpec(strPassPhrase.getBytes()));
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    String encrypted = "3764b8140ae470bda73f7ebed3c33b0895f70c3497c85f39043345128a4bc3b3";
    String decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encrypted)));
    System.out.println("Text Decryted : " + decrypted);
```

With the above code, I get an exception `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`

The key was generated using openssl

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -k mypassphrase -P
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like currently you *have* to use Suitescript to decrypt messages if it was encrypted using SuiteScript.
See suiteanswers: 35099

The workaround suggested is to use an external javascript library to encrypt/decrypt. We ended up using OpenJS on the javascript, but on the java side had to make sure the defaults were adjusted according to what is setup on the javascript side. The Java APIs were more flexible in this regard than the javascript ones.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are encrypting with AES, and decrypting with DES. I think the ciphertext needs to be decrypted with the same symmetric algorithm that you used to encrypt.